# Transforming XML to a list of Elements in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, collections

This is a follow-up to my previous question. I would like to linearize an XML tree eagerly (not lazy). I assume for simplicity that an XML tree is a tree of `Elem` nodes, so I am transforming an XML to a sequence of `Elem`.

```
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node}
import PartialFunction._

def linearize(node: Node): List[Node] = {
  val children = node.child.filter(cond(_) {case _: Elem => true}).toList
  children match {
    case Nil => List(node)
    case list => node :: list.flatMap(linearize)
  }
}
```

It seems working but I don't like that `val children = ...` How would you suggest change/fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already transforming `node.child` into `List`, you don't need to match on it, you can flatMap directly, since it will return Nil in case the `child` is empty. The following code yields the same result as your solution for a simple test case.

```
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node}
import PartialFunction._

def linearize(node: Node): List[Node] = {

  node :: node.child.flatMap {
    case e: Elem => linearize(e)
    case _ => Nil
  }.toList

}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if `node.child` contains non-`Elem` node ?

Comment: Well, that is up to you to decide what you want to do with them. I just added the match to `Elem` so it behaves like the function posted on the question. PS. If this answers your question completely, can you please mark this as the answer instead of upvoting? If the answer is incomplete, I can complement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the tree in both [depth-first and breath-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first) fashion. I've created functions for these two modes. Both are tail-recursive so you can save some stack frames at the expense of heap.

```
import scala.xml.{ Elem, Node }

def linearizeDepthFirst(node: Node): List[Node] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(toVisit: Vector[Node], result: Vector[Node]): List[Node] = {
    if (toVisit.isEmpty) {
      result.toList
    } else {
      val children = toVisit.head.collect({ case e: Elem => e }).toVector
      loop(children ++ toVisit.tail, result ++ children)
    }
  }

  loop(Vector(node), Vector(node))
}

def linearizeBreadthFirst(node: Node): List[Node] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(toVisit: Vector[Node], result: Vector[Node]): List[Node] = {
    if (toVisit.isEmpty) {
      result.toList
    } else {
      val children = toVisit.head.collect({ case e: Elem => e }).toVector
      loop(toVisit.tail ++ children, result ++ children)
    }
  }

  loop(Vector(node), Vector(node))
}
```