# --Is this an example of breadth first or depth first seach?

Tags: javascript, computer-science

Here is a simple function to traverse the entire document object model.  I was tying to understand if this is breadth first or depth first and how to understand why:

```
var traverseDOM = function () {
  function traverse (parent) {
    // mark 1
    _(parent.childNodes).forEach((child) => {
      traverse(child);
    }
    // mark 2
  }
  traverse(document.body);
}
```

It appears to be depth first search from this related [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first).

It can be further classified according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

InOrder, PreOrder, and PostOrder.

Comment: It's DFS. BFS is not that simple.

Comment: Execute it by hand, and see what order it processes the nodes in the tree.

Comment: By the way that won't terminate for circular graphs...

Comment: Is the question on whether you understand DFS or BFS, or you just want to understand this specific example?

Comment: @pedromss It's traversing a DOM, which is a hierarchy and doesn't allow circularities.

Comment: It will go "down" a level before it goes across the same level (traversing siblings).  Therefore, it is depth-first.

Comment: @Barmar if this person thinks that DFS is this he/she may want to use it in the context of circular graphs and then oh well.. Was just pointing out something that wasn't explicit.

Comment: @stackoverflow Yes, that's true. For mark1 vs mark2, that could be called "pre-order" vs "post-order" DFS, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search

Comment: @pedromss Both DFS and BFS will loop infinitely on a circular graph, unless you add checks for revisiting a node. That's an orthogonal issue.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following tree:

[image: Initial tree]

You start with `traverse(1)`:

```
traverse(1)
```

[image: traverse(1)]

And after "mark 1" the method will start looping over all child nodes, calling `traverse` for each. The first, `traverse(1.1)`, will "barge in on the execution":

```
traverse(1)
traverse(1.1)
```

[image: traverse(1.1)]

As `traverse(1.1)` hits "mark 1", it will start to proceed *its* children and call `traverse(1.1.1)`:

```
traverse(1)
traverse(1.1)
traverse(1.1.1)
```

[image: traverse(1.1.1)]

Since "1.1.1" does not have any children, `traverse(1.1.1)` reaches "mark 2" and the execution flow will return to the `forEach` loop of the parent method `traverse(1.1)`:

```
traverse(1)
traverse(1.1)
```

[image: traverse(1.1)]

The loop continues and `traverse` will be called for the second child, "1.1.2":

```
traverse(1)
traverse(1.1)
traverse(1.1.2)
```

[image: traverse(1.1.2)]

After both children of "1.1" have been processed, `traverse(1.1)` reaches "mark 2" and the execution flow is now back in the `forEach` loop of `traverse(1)`:

```
traverse(1)
```

[image: traverse(1)]

Proceeding with "1.2":

```
traverse(1)
traverse(1.2)
```

[image: traverse(1.2)]

I'll stop here, but you should get the hang of it. What you can see is that "1.1.1" and "1.1.2" are visited *before* "1.2", making it a depth-first search. A breadth-first search would visit "1.2" and "1.3" before "1.1.1".

Comment: what tool you used to draw the graph? great explanation and great job!

Answer (score 1):

As Eugene mentioned, it is an example of Depth First Search algorithm. If you notice in line#4, it is using recursion and passing the first child it has searched:

```
    `traverse(child);`
```

and this line is being called `for each child` in the parent node.

**UPDATE:** Adding a comment for clarity: 
"as soon as it gets "first" child, it calls traverse function again on that child, forcing the system to go down until it hits a node."

Comment: While correct this isn't good reasoning, or it isn't fully reasoned out.  Breadth-first search will also traverse child nodes.

Comment: hitting the first child is the first thing it does each time, therefore it gets deep asap

Comment: @Amy, as soon as it gets "first" child, it calls traverse function again on that child, forcing the system to go down until it hits a node. Let me update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user3815252 don't explain it to *me*.  flesh out the reasoning in your answer.