# Deserialize a binary tree without recursion

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I wrote a code for Deserialization of a binary tree using recursion.Can someone help me tweak it in a way that i can eliminate recursion because i have found that i am not allowed to use recursion in my task

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NO_CHILD 0
//node
struct Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node* left, *right;
};
//create a node
Node* _NewNode(int key)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return (temp);
}
//extract binary tree from text
void _ReadBinaryTree(Node *&root, FILE *file)
{
    //read element;if there are no more elements or the elemnt has NO_CHILD stop
    int value;
    if ( !fscanf(file, "%d ", &value) || value == NO_CHILD)
       return;
    //otherwise create the node and recursion for its children
    root = _NewNode(value);
    _ReadBinaryTree(root->left, file);
    _ReadBinaryTree(root->right, file);
}

//preorder traversal
void _Preorder(Node *root)
{
    if (root)
    {
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        _Preorder(root->left);
        _Preorder(root->right);
    }
}
int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    Node *root1 = NULL;
    file = fopen("tree.txt", "r");
    _ReadBinaryTree(root1, file);
    printf("Preorder traversal:\n");
    _Preorder(root1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example:
    If i read 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 5 0 7 0 0
    it will display a binary tree traversed in preorder like this

```
            1
    2           5
3       4           7
```

Comment: Building a binary tree without recursion? This exercise author has a twisted mind...

Comment: Use a stack data structure

Comment: BTW, as far as I know a single preorder traversal sequence is not sufficient to reconstruct the tree.

Comment: @Ron, but, but, there's the new keyword :-)

Comment: To do this without recursion, you need a data structure to hold pointers to the nodes along the path to the current node.  Implementation details don't matter so much, but it would function basically as a stack.  If your Node structure had a parent pointer, then the tree itself would serve that purpose, but I'm supposing that you are not permitted to make that modification.

Comment: Note also that if the zeroes in your example input are supposed to represent the absence of nodes, then your example output does not appear to match that input.

Comment: Why does code use `if ( !fscanf(file, "%d ", &value)...`?  `fscanf()` here could return 0,1 or `EOF`.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I'm looking at the zeroes in the example input, and thinking that they correspond to the absence of child nodes at corresponding positions in the tree.  With that included, I think the pre-order traversal *is* sufficient to reconstruct the tree, though the result is not what the OP presents.

Answer (score 1):

As your example is type of breadth-first algorithm, it may be solved with queue (look at [Breadth First Vs Depth First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first)). It is possible also without queue using iterative depth first approach (look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search).