# Algorithm for "balanced" breadth-first search

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm looking for references for an algorithm that conducts a breadth-first tree search in a balanced manner that is resilient in a situation where

- we expect most nodes to have few children, but
- a few nodes may have a many (possibly infinitely many) children.

Consider this simple tree (modified from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first)):

```
     A
   /   \
  B     C
 /     /  \
D     E    F
|    /|\    \
G   HIJ...   K
```

Depth-first visits nodes in this order:

```
A B D G C E H I J ... F K
```

Breadth-first visits nodes in this order:

```
A B C D E F G H I J ... K
```

The balanced breadth-first algorithm that I have in mind would visit nodes in this order:

```
A B C D E G F H K I J ...
```

Note how

- we visit G before F, and
- we visit K after H but before I.

G is deeper than F, but it is an only child of B whereas F is a second child of C and must share its search priority with E.  Similarly between K and the many children H, I, J, ... of E.

I call this "balanced" because a node with lots of children cannot choke the algorithm.  Concretely, if E has  (infinitely) many nodes then a pure breadth-first strategy would *never* reach K, whereas the "balanced" algorithm would still reach K after H but before the other children of E.

<sub>(The reader who does not like  can attain a similar effect with a large but still finite number such as "the greatest number of steps any practical search algorithm will ever make, plus 1".)</sub>

I can only imagine that this style of search or something like it must have been the subject of much research and practical application.  I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction.  Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to specify exactly what the logic behind "balanced" is, so it is clear what you would need to be the order in *all* scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your tree to a different kind of representation. In this new representation, each node has at most two links: one to its *leftmost* child, and one to its *right* sibling.

```
     A
   /   \
  B     C
 /     /  \
D     E    F
|    /|\    \
G   HIJ...   K
```

⇓

```
     A
   /  
  B --> C
 /     /  
D     E -> F
|    /      \
G   /        K
   /
  H -> I -> J -> ...
```

Then treat this representation as a normal binary tree, and traverse it breadth-first. It may have an infinite height, but like with any binary tree, the width at any particular level is finite.

Answer (score 0):

depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, A*-search (and others) only differ in how you handle the list of "nodes still to visit".
(I assume you always process the node at the start of the list next)

- depth-first-search: append new nodes at the front of the list
- breadth-first-search: add new nodes to the end of the list
- A*-search: insert new nodes in the list according to costs+heuristic

So you need to formalize how to insert new nodes to the list to fulfill your requirements.